# Relevance of Industry 4.0 to Automotive software engineering

Tags: definitions, industry-4.0

I have read through the Industry 4.0 reference architecture (RAMI) and I believe I have some understanding of I4.0.

I was thinking how can this effect Automotive software engineering. How can I adapt this in ASE (some technical components, which I am not sure of). Can some of the technical aspect of I4.0 be adapted into some reference architecture in ASE like Autosar?

---

I first posted this question on stackoverflow, which went unnoticed and someone recommended to post it here for a better discussion. I want to say upfront that reasoning behind this post is just a technical discussion.

Comment: Hi vahuniyab, I think this sort of question is to broad to be answered effectively here. If you ask about some specific part of two specs (with references), and how they relate, you might get a better answer. This is not really a forum for discussion, it's possible you might get some better insight in [chat].

Comment: @SeanHoulihane, I do understand your point. But I am looking for the specific content myself. I thought some users here might have some ideas.

Comment: Agreed, but this is not a forum, it is more of a reference site - so your question is not a 'good' question. Adding links to your question is probably mandatory, making it more specific might avoid it being closed by the other users. Since this site is in Beta, we need to show we can adhere to the SE philosophy.

Comment: @vahuniyab, welcome to IoT Stack Exchange!  We are glad you are here!  As Sean said, adding some precision and references to your question will make a huge difference.  [Try taking the tour](http://iot.stackexchange.com/tour) and reading the [how to ask](http://iot.stackexchange.com/help/asking) page for reference on how to ask questions here.  As this question stands, it risks getting closed as "Too Broad."

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you're asking, but it *sounds* like you're asking whether Industry 4.0 is being adapted for the automotive industry.  If I'm misunderstanding you, edit your post to clarify.  However, as that question stands, the answer is yes.  From [an article on AutomotiveManufacturingSolutions.com](http://www.automotivemanufacturingsolutions.com/magazines/industry-4-0):

> The advance of the smart factory continues to transform the landscape of automotive manufacturing. With vehicle makers and their suppliers implementing I4.0 at such a fast rate, what benefits are being realised and what challenges are being encountered?
>
> Issued with the July-August 2017 edition of AMS, Industry 4.0 will examine automotive manufacturing’s relationship with the digital revolution, including:
>
> • focus on the practical application of data-driven manufacturing
> • interviews with key OEM and tier supplier executives implementing I4.0
> • case studies across the automotive manufacturing process
>
> Industry 4.0 will also include our popular From the Industry section – bespoke content that presents your insight, advice and technology to our global readership of OEMs and major tier suppliers.

In other words, they are working on several possible applications of Industry 4.0 for the automotive industry:

- Manufacturing (practically implementing it)
- Talking with suppliers to implement Industry 4.0
- Studying the way things are done in the manufacturing process (presumably to hone abilities to implement)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's already been implemented in Automotive industry. I was it's technical aspects usage in Automotive Software industry. Both are quite different.

Comment: Sorry about the typo in my previous comment. " I was asking about I4.0's technical aspects portability in Automotive software engineering"